# Bootstrap : Fixing navbar at top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Tried everything to make navbar fix to the top in bootstrap, but nothing works. I've already tried `position : relative` and `position : absolute`. Any help appreciated!

HTML:

```
    <section style="background-color: #E8E8EA">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-top: 2vw; margin-right: 3vw; position: fixed;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search rt"></span>     Search</a></li>
            <li><a class="qt" href="#"><span class="strike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>      About Us</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="strike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>      Education</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="strike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>      Consumer Service</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="border-radius: 50%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 5px; margin-top: -5px;"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
color: black;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

**EDIT** : Implemented this one page scroll in the page : https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

Comment: removing `style="margin-top: 2vw; margin-right: 3vw; position: fixed;"` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope. It didn't

Comment: check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/. This demonstrate the same.

Comment: where do you want to fix the navbar? To the top of the window or to the top of the section?.
Don't really understand why you placed it inside a section when you dont need it.

Comment: I've used one page scroll. Hence I had to put it inside a section

Comment: The correct answer is given already. For more details just refer to the documentation and copy-paste the standard solution. Best regards,

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? Still don't get it? Is it a one page? you can have a one page and still have a nav outside a section. like here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 it's just `fixed-top`. Why are you using relative and absolute?

Answer (score 0):

`navbar-fixed-top` shall do the job (your additional statement `position: fixed;` is redundant and should be removed). As an example, refer to the web page which implements the required functionality using Bootstrap CSS: [www.alexanderbell.us](http://alexanderbell.us/). Corresponding verbatim HTML : `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg-grey-dark">` ( `bg-grey-dark` is a custom class setting background and could be excluded as it's indifferent to the positioning).

On a separate note: the better practice would be avoiding in-line styling as shown in your case (i.e. `style="margin-top: 2vw; margin-right: 3vw; position: fixed;"`>. Instead, extend the existing class `.navbar-fixed-top` in your custom CSS file, or CSS included in the `<head>` section.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Well, I've provided you with detailed solution/explanation and fully-functional page built on this solution. It's a bit unclear what exactly are you trying to achieve and how it is different from already existing solutions(s). If you can add more clarity to your question, then the solution could be customized per that clarified requirements. Anyway, good luck with your project. Best rgds,

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your full example and what you are trying to achieve.

Your code is already fixed in the top.
Probably the section you placed the navbar has some css you don't let as see.

here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/L1eczuno/

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-top: 2vw; margin-right: 3vw; position: fixed;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search rt"></span>     Search</a></li>
        <li><a class="qt" href="#"><span class="strike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>      About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="strike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>      Education</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="strike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>      Consumer Service</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="border-radius: 50%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 5px; margin-top: -5px;"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

 <div id="test" class="jumbotron" style:"padding-top:30px">
    <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
    <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a></p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
#test {
    margin-top: 87px;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

André

Comment: That's why I've provided the link to the github repo for one page scroll. Its not possible to describe the entire code here. I think, the CSS there might be creating some problem, but don't know where, since I tried tweaking that too

Comment: The example you provided works. So cant help you further